# Is it possible to manage a sticky table for rate limiting using HAProxy - Lua?

Tags: lua, haproxy, internal-load-balancer

I am using HAProxy as a load balancer & i have a lua script which returns the backend name to haproxy.cfg. Wanted to implement rate limiting for my application.

I know that we can use sticky tables (as below) in haproxy.cfg to achieve rate limiting.

---

stick-table type ip size 1m expire 60s store http_req_cnt

acl exceeds_limit hdr_ip(x-forwarded-for,-1),table_http_req_cnt(incoming) ge 10

http-request tarpit if exceeds_limit

http-request track-sc0 hdr_ip(x-forwarded-for,-1)

---

Wanted to implement the same using lua. Is it possible to access that sticky table using lua.

Thanks in advance.